# Confusion about key definition for SPC

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, help

Yesterday, I tried to do something like

```
(define-keymap " " #'foo)
```

and I got the error message that `" "` is not a valid key definition.  OK, `key-valid-p` also says so and I figured out I should have used

```
(define-keymap "SPC" #'foo)
```

instead.  However, I also noticed that

```
(kbd "SPC")
```

returns the string `" "` that I started with and that confuses me.  Isn't `kbd` supposed to return valid key definitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kbd` returns *internal* key definitions, not external key descriptions. It takes as its argument a string of the name that Emacs help uses to describe the key.

Witht the "old" functions for defining etc. key sequences you can use `kbd` to pass them the internal definitions they expect, passing an external key description to `kbd`.  IOW, you can use `kbd` as a way of not bothering with any internal key definitions.

The `KEY` used by the "new" `*keymap*` functions is what you might pass to `kbd` when using the "old" `define-key`: a key-sequence description.

E.g., you would write `(define-key (kbd "SPC") #'foo)`, so you write `(keymap-set "SPC" #'foo)` or `(define-keymap "SPC" #'foo)`.

So yes, you can use `"SPC"`, which is how Emacs help functions describe the space-char key. But you can't use `" "`, as that's not (never has been) a key description.

The test used by the `*keymap*` functions is `key-valid-p`: `"SPC"` succeeds that test and `" "` doesn't.

Also, a space char is used to separate keystrokes in key descriptions.